# Load content of ViewPager before paging

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

How can I load next page content of a `ViewPager` before paging. Imagine I'm using a `ViewPager` to display a book and each page is a fragment which is added to the `ViewPager` and I want the fragment being loaded before paging the book and user didn't feel the lag while paging the book page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(k)` to cache all entities of ViewPager from n-k to n+k.

Comment: Yes but it works only when we load a page once and the first time it only keep n-k not n+k (before first loading )

Comment: Can you show the order in which you setting Adapter to ViewPager and setOffscreenPageLimit? Because as I see from code inside ViewPager it should work.

Comment: There is only one order in which we initialize the adaper by our custom adapter and then pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5); for example.

Comment: Maybe it is initialized before and the view of the next page will not update fast :-?? any idea how to update the next view??

Comment: just to be sure, did you set large enough OffscreenPageLimit?

Comment: yes , I th9nk you are right and it is initialized and I need to refresh the incoming view. thx

Answer (score 1):

ViewPager itself handles it.. For instance, if you are currently at item n, the FragmentPagerAdapter calls the onCreateView() of fragments at n-1, n and n+1.

Comment: But it work when a page is loaded before and didn't work for new pages.